# Google Play Game Services: SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider

Tags: android, google-play-services

This is what I am getting when trying to load google Images:

```
08-23 12:03:41.247: W/ImageView(23831): Unable to open content: content://com.google.android.gms.games.background/images/1066b186/2
08-23 12:03:41.247: W/ImageView(23831): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.google.android.gms.games.provider.GamesContentProvider from ProcessRecord{413da0f8 23831:[package_name]/10161} (pid=23831, uid=10161) that is not exported from uid 10045
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Can you please post what code is causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the "GamesContentProvider" that is used by you or some of the classes you use requires a permission that you have not added in your manifest file. Take a look at the documentation of the classes (in GooglePlayServices) you use and see if there is something about any permission you have to add to your app in order to be able to use the documented functionality.